# Outbound Email and Add Error are not working together

Tags: trigger, singleemailmessage

Actually i want to send email whenever duplicate record will create in salesforce and also show the error "Duplicate Account found" . I'm using for sending email through Outbound Email for salesforce and for showing error i'm using addError() method in trigger , when i'm using both together then email is not sending to owner that i have written the logic for that , indirectly outbound email is getting stop working.
Could anyone please help me for figure out this issue ?
I want use both sending email and show error also. Anyone have solution to do it in different way because i saw some blogs , that says outbound email doesn't work when we use addError() method.
Please give me solution of this problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do both, in most cases. Using `addError()` blocks the transaction from committing successfully to the database (assuming the originator of the DML operation is not using a partial-success operation).

When the transaction does not commit, it also blocks all other transactional operations, such as sending email, enqueuing future methods, scheduling batches, and so forth. Only non-transactional Platform Events are not rolled back.

What you are attempting to do does not fit well within the way Salesforce works. Typically you should present an error and block the save if data does not meet expectations, and send an email to notify the user of saved data that requires their attention. Doing both doesn't really make sense.

Additionally, consider using native Duplicate Management functionality rather than using an Apex trigger to perform duplicate management. It is lighter-weight and requires no code at all.

Comment: Thank You so much @David  ,You're right but is there any other way to solve this problem.
Can i do using platform event trigger ?

Comment: The problem doesn't really make sense to me. If you are presenting an error to the user in the UI, where they are guaranteed to see it, what is the point of sending an email?

Comment: Yes@David , I agree with you but client wants this. Thank You So Much for helping me.

Comment: I would suggest that sometimes the hard part of a consulting job is explaining to the client that what they want doesn't make sense or is impossible. Were I on this project, I would tell the client as much. You _might_ be able to do this in a Platform Event trigger, but I believe PE triggers cannot use Org-Wide Email Addresses.

Comment: I used Platform Event triggeralso for that but it's not sending the email , but it's publishing perfectly. I just create Platform Event Trigger and into this i wrote logic for outbound email and publish the platform event from another object trigger that i want to show error on that object. Error is showing but email isn't sending. Do you have any idea how we can do using Platform Event Trigger.